# How can I check if a string is a valid sed expression?

Tags: sed

I am working on a function that needs to parse a string and see if it is a valid sed expression. I was using a basic regex for this, but someone pointed out the regex (a) only allows sed expressions in the form of `s/foo/bar` and (b) does not allow escaping `/` characters. I would like something that passes the following test:

```
s/foo/bar/ - pass
s|foo|bar/ - pass
s/foo\//bar\// - pass
s/foo\/bar/ - fail
s/foo - fail
```

This is certainly not a comprehensive test suite, but it should be enough to make me happy.

I'm writing this in C++, but answers in any language will be fine as long as I can easily understand the algorithm being used and can fairly easily port it to C++/Qt.

Comment: Why do you want the first two examples to pass? Also, are you aware that `sed` supports many more functions than just search and replace, including labels and conditional branches, thus making the language turing-complete? I think the sanest option here would be to rip that parsing code out of the `sed` codebase...

Comment: first two are not valid sed commands.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that sed expressions need the trailing slash. I'm not sure why; I probably should have known better.

Answer (score 2):

Just run an existing sed implementation and check its exit status with an empty file as input. Sed *always* returns zero exit status, unless with GNU sed you would use `q` command. Check the following bash session transcript that runs your expression in a loop and outputs similar to yours output depending on `sed "<expr>" /dev/null` exit status.

```
$ for i in "s/foo/bar" "s|foo|bar" "s/foo\//bar\//" "s/foo\/bar/" "s/foo"; do
> if sed "$i" /dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
> echo "$i - pass"; else echo "$i - fail"; fi; done
s/foo/bar - fail
s|foo|bar - fail
s/foo\//bar\// - pass
s/foo\/bar/ - fail
s/foo - fail
```

Alternatively, you could link with an existing implementation of `sed` and re-use the internals. The simplest here looks like to be [busybox sed.c](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/editors/sed.c) as it is a single file, so it's easy to modify and [parse_subst_cmd()](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/editors/sed.c#L437) might be of interest to you. However, Busybox is under GPL2, GNU sed under GPL3, so BSD sed might more of interest under BSD license if it matters.

Comment: Your statement that "_sed always returns zero exit status_" is clearly false, otherwise this test wouldn't work.  Did you mean "always returns zero exit status __when its program is valid__"?  That's almost true (`w` command can fail the program, for example, and you mentioned `q`/`Q`).  It's also possible to DoS this test with an infinite loop such as `:a`, `ba`, which will never terminate (so perhaps worth constraining with a very small `ulimit -t` if you're using this to validate untrusted input).

Comment: The problem is that this app is distributed not just to Unix-based systems but also Windows, and an Android or even iOS port may very well happen, so I don't think simply invoking `sed` is a good option. I guess I could try bundling existing sed source code; the app is GPL3, so Busybox or GNU sed should probably be fine.